# Is it possible to access kubernetes dashboard directly in browser in Azure Kuberenetes Service (AKS) (without additional commands)

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

When I run `kubectl cluster-info` in AKS I get this:

> kubernetes-dashboard is running at https://clusterUrl/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard/proxy

This url is reachable in browser, but only returns 401.

I am wondering if it is possible to log in to Azure in some way so that this url is accessible? Would be quite convenient to access it directly.

Comment: You can try to use the Azure CLI command [`az aks browser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/aks?view=azure-cli-latest#az-aks-browse) to show the AKS dashboard in the browser.

Answer (score 3):

using kubectl proxy, you can access the dashboard

```
[root@ae740dbd82bf /]# kubectl proxy
Starting to serve on 127.0.0.1:8001
```

open your browser and navigate to
http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/

If you want to access it externally then you have two choices

1. define service port as NodePort. Then you would be able to access dashboard on any CLUSTER_HOST:NODEPORT
2. Deploy an ingress controller and define a rule between the dashboard dns and the dashboard kubernetes service

Comment: Yes, that works, but I was wondering if it is possible to reach directly, without a local proxy

Comment: just keep in mind it might not be a smart idea to expose dashboard to the internet

Comment: @4c74356b41 Well I guess API management is already exposed (and protected with Azure stuff), so it won't be worse :)

Comment: @PEkambaram Thanks for help, I was not really trying to expose the service myself, but trying to use what's already set up by AKS if it is possible, I don't really want to manage this myself

Comment: well, those are 2 different things. dashboard might have bugs, you might misconfigure it, etc